# Avoid Unchecked Casting Warnings in Parameterized Type Casting

Tags: java, casting, parameterized-types

Is it possible to avoid the `unchecked` warning when typecasting a parameterized type object? For example, below is the actual situation I face, `var1` is of type `JComboBox<RandomType>` I wish to store it in a `Map` and then retrieve it forcing me into the following situation.

```
    JComboBox<RandomType> var1 = new JComboBox<RandomType>();

    Object varRaw = var1;

    JComboBox<RandomType> var2 = (JComboBox<RandomType>) varRaw;

    JComboBox<RandomType> var3;
    if (JComboBox.class.isAssignableFrom(varRaw.getClass())) {
        var3 = JComboBox.class.cast(varRaw);
    }
```

Both the regular cast and the conditional casting results in the same warning.

Is it even possible to avoid that warning in this situation without having to use the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation?

Comment: you could always simply throw the suppresswarnings (unchecked) annotation onto the method, although I actually would like to see a 'proper' answer for this.

Comment: Its true, I have browsed over many pages, guides and documentations but could not find an answer which cleans casts the object.

Comment: I would have to say that this is a question that I have a significant amount of interest in.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is NO, there is not a better alternative (that i know). But I am not an authoritative source and seems unwieldy to prove that EVERY other alternative does not arise a 'false' warning.

I have come to a point of assuming the lesser evil of having some warnings around (yes there is `@SupressWarnings unchecked` but I would like to know if something noteworthy arises). For the same reason i would frown upon the `javac -Xlint:unchecked` non-standard option

Other sources also say it is not possible to supress unchecked warnings in all cases (particularly when dealing with libraries not fully adapted to generics). For example in this [Generics tutorial](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ006) the author says

> Is it possible to eliminate all "unchecked" warnings? - Almost

And then she goes into some unwieldy technical explanation that overwhelm me. Therefore I don't know if what she says counts as proof of what.

I just know I can't prove unicorns don't exist. But if I don't have notice of anyone actually registering their existence, it is fair that i assume they don't. That's [Falsafiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability), just take this wicked technical problem instead of stupid unicorns.